# The OleDbReader is always showing this error

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have this set of command.

```
using (conn)
{
    conn.Open();

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT ID FROM User WHERE UserPassword= '@oldpassword'", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldpassword", currentPassword);
    OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    reader.Read();
    int userID = reader.GetInt32(0);
}
```

Is my SQL statement correct?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? `User` is a reserved word in some and the statement will cause an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the exact error you get, I believe this is the correct code:

```
using (conn)
{
    conn.Open();

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT ID FROM [User] WHERE UserPassword = ?", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldpassword", currentPassword);
    OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        IdLabel.Text = reader.GetInt32(0).ToString();
    }
}
```

Specify the table between square brackets because `User` is a reserved word and use a question mark (without surrounding quotes) as variable placeholder.

If you want to use the `userID` outside of the using statement, you'll need to declare it above that statement.

Comment: Thanks, it is the "User" table that is causing the error. Now,I've renamed that table and can now use the WCF. thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

> *The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement*

So you need to remove single quotes from the query as well as use `?` in place of named parameter.

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT ID FROM [User] WHERE UserPassword= ?", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add(currentPassword);

OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.HasRows)
{
    int userID = reader.GetInt32(0);
}
```

Comment: It's still not working. 
I've tried searching for web sites to web sites about SQL query and still not working.

Comment: @ITStudent I have updated my post to show the entire code. Please check it and let me know if there is any problem..